# How to set objects unique for each User in django?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models

i have a question about django-models that how i can set field to unique=True of Table in django  for each User. I have Table Token below, and when i added new token, it't auto create tokenprofile by signals django built-in, i want to unique uid of ProfileToken for each User. Show me how. Thanks

```py
from django.db import models
from accounts.models import CustomeUser
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
import facebook
# Create your models here.
class Token(models.Model):
    access_token = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomeUser, related_name='tokens', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.access_token



class TokenProfile(models.Model):
    token = models.OneToOneField(Token, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    uid = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=False)
    profile_picture_link = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    profile_link = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __str__(self):
        return '{0} - {1}'.format(self.name, self.uid)


def create_profile_token(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        access_token = instance.access_token
        graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token=access_token)
        info = graph.get_object('me')
        name = info['name']
        uid = info['id']
        profile_picture_link = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/{0}/picture?type=small&amp;redirect=true'.format(uid)
        profile_link = 'https://www.facebook.com/{0}'.format(uid)
        profile_token = TokenProfile.objects.create(token=instance, name=name, uid=uid, profile_picture_link=profile_picture_link, profile_link=profile_link)


post_save.connect(create_profile_token, sender=Token)
```

Comment: If you want a unique `Token` for each `User`, why do you use a `ForeignKey`? It should be a `OneToOneField` like you have for the `TokenProfile`. That way each user can only have one token (and hence one token_profile).

Comment: Sorry, my question is set unique for uid in table TokenProfile, i have update my question, sorry it's my fault @dirkgroten

Comment: then why do you set `unique=False`? Just set `unique=True`.

Comment: @dirkgroten Because i just want to set unique for each user only. Example: I have two User that user1 and user2, user1 have Token with uid 12345 and that i unique for user1 and usert2 can have that uid, if i set unique = True, user2 can't have that uid. Do you understand? sorry for my bad English. Thanks

Comment: Examples make wonders :-) Always try to include one to make clear what you're doing. You can't set it at the database level. But you can add that to the `clean()` method of `TokenProfile` (e.g. `other_profiles = TokenProfile.objects.filter(token__user=self.token.user, uid=self.uid).exclude(pk=self.pk)` which should be empty) and call `profile_token.clean()` before saving it, or do that in the `TokenProfile.save()` method, raising an exception and catch the exception in your `create_profile_token()` signal receiver.

Comment: @dirkgroten can you give me an example about code. does clean() is built-in method of Models? Thanks

Comment: read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) and [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods). The `clean()` method is called by a ModelForm automatically when validating the form, but in your case you don't have a form so you'll have to call it manually. The `save()` method might be the proper way for you to do this, but it's more difficult to handle the error you raise in a user-friendly way.

Comment: Thanks for help.@dirkgroten

Comment: @dirkgroten. i call that method in signals? or i have to override save method and call this?