# "unique = True" - Django models - Unique for each user not unique for all data submitted by everyone

Tags: django, unique, web-deployment

I have a models in Django currently and I have made a field `unique=True` so that no duplicates are submitted to the database. My problem is that it extends to all users. By this I mean that User 1 should be able to submit "**Example1**" and "**Example2**" and should never be able to submit "**Example1**" or "**Example2**" again and then User2 should come along and also be able to submit "**Example1**" and "**Example2**" but they cant because User 1 already submitted it. 
Is there a way where I can get somewhat of a `unique=True` but separately for each user and not just conjoined like it is now.

Thanks in advance. Code Below.

The problem resides in `type =`  and my users are being defined by ForeignKey also.

```
class Field_Repo1(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=True, related_name="Field_Repo1", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Title of Field')
    type = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, unique=True, null=True, verbose_name='Field')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-type']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user) or 'NONE'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('repo1')
```

**UPDATED CODE THAT WORKS**

```
class Field_Repo1(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=True, related_name="Field_Repo1", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
title = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Title of Field')
type = models.CharField(max_length=22, choices=FIELDS, verbose_name='Field')

class Meta:
    ordering = ['-type']
    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['user', 'type'], name='unique type for each user')
    ]

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.user) or 'NONE'

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('repo1')
```

Comment: Please read the comments https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56145323/how-to-set-objects-unique-for-each-user-in-django

Comment: if user1 creates example1 then user2 also can create example1 but user2 cant create example1 again? is that what you want? each user should only have unique titles for himself?

Comment: `unique_together` meta option…?

Comment: @Mirza715 That link was somewhat helpful and I don't know how I didn't stumble across it in my research but It is defining user in a much different way and I have built my website around a different way of defining and can only use that method as a last-ditch effort. Thank you though.

Comment: @MojixCoder Yes, that is exactly what I'm looking for. Sorry I was having a hard time wording it.

Comment: @deceze "unique together" is an interesting idea but it makes two fields unique together. I tried it and tried tieing the user field and the type field together but it, unfortunately, does nothing. I do need to connect the user field and the type field somehow but almost in an opposite way where they can differentiate each other.

Comment: You want unique combinations. (User 1, A), (User 1, B), (User 2, A), (User 2, B), and then no more (User 1, A) allowed. That’s exactly what `unique_together` does. What exactly have you tried with it?

Comment: @deceze I ran the following code in the Meta section of my model.     class Meta:
        ordering = ['-type']
        unique_together = ('user', 'type',). This didn't yield any different results. I still get the same error. Unless I'm using it wrong it seems that it is combining the uniqueness so that "Example1" cant be submitted to user OR to type twice if it is already in one of them. I am new to this function and have been looking at the documentation but maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `UniqueConstraint`:

```
class Field_Repo1(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=True, related_name="Field_Repo1", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Title of Field')
    type = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, unique=True, null=True, verbose_name='Field')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user) or 'NONE'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('repo1')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-type']
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['user', 'title'], name='unique title for each user')
        ]
```

Comment: I tried this exact example but switched "title" out in the UniqueContraint to be "type" because that's the field I'm trying to make unique separately for each user. It didn't work and I tried a few different things but there were no abnormal characteristics it simply just gave the error "Field_ repo1 with this Field already exists." and that was after running the makemigrations and migrate. Nothing failed but nothing new happened.

Comment: I apologize. This does work. This concept does work but for the final testing, my models were a bit different. I am running type off of a dropdown and that changed some things. I also had two Meta's in my models one for ordering and one for UniqueContraint so that changed some things as well. Ill update the final code that works in the original post above.